# Conflicting libpng.16.16.dylib

Tags: python, x11, dynamic-library

On my mac book (OS X 10.12.4) I have two `libpng.16.16.dylib`: one in `/opt/X11/bin`, for which `otool` reports

```
/opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib:
    /opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 43.0.0, current version 43.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

and another in `Users/me/anaconda/lib` with anaconda's python installation, for which `otool` reports

```
/Users/me/anaconda/lib/libpng16.16.dylib:
    @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

In my start-up script, I set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/opt/X11/lib`.

Now, when I want to `import matplotlib` from `ipython3` (of the anaconda distribution), I get an error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/walter1/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/walter1/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _png.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 44.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 43.0.0
```

So it appears that `dlopen` tries `/opt/X11/lib/libpng.16.16.dylib` rather than the one under `anaconda`.

Is there a way to avoid this w/o changing `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I cannot remember why I set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this, but what would the effect be of omitting `/opt/X11/lib` from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of some ways.

- Backup your `/opt/X11/lib/libpng.16.16.dylib`. And replace the file with either symlink to the file under anaconda or directly paste the file.
- I think the environment variables can have multiple paths, like $PATH variable. I found that the path you have in front has the precedence over the ones that are written behind it. For example, if your path is `/usr1/:/usr2/` then it should check the `usr1` directory first and see if the required file exists, before moving to the second one. So you could possibly put your anaconda path in front of the `/opt/X11/lib/libpng.16.16.dylib`.
- I believe symlinking the file is the best way. I have experienced that kind of things before, I just had to add a symlink and it's fixed.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35570229/1509809) answer might explain your last question.